# LinkedIn API Share Content with symfony return 403

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to connect one app to linkedin in order to share content for a company page. I use symfony 5.4 in order to.

I do the following step:

- create a code : ok
- create a token : ok
- get user credential with the token : ok

I send this request:

yes here is the response I get :

```
TraceableHttpClient->request('POST', 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts', array('headers' => array('Authorization: Bearer AQWkl2rmtRNpKP6ir_n_y7GloBnUJI--gp6hy0xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-LedwHSBHATYSN3878kPadWjVH9Fm-_NdDnEau0rpElZe2C4UglKTpFFZDIs2tpT1o1N_oYjWwl6AmaduaG_1v-ZS76BKrR2RLxhvDhBaqTA9U_kIWleQPpRfV_hYGYZn5ILHbSOw6PnfxFo_3UulB-8QyyeS00W8l1pAKr3cVpqxsDhfPFYZLazIGFePfaEFxlqEqZsJjSrj1jUewejLzdojs8gqcqY8_-DKexWCCuNMsFdOQNMCs5XFjw', 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0'), 'json' => array('author' => 'urn:li:person:2aw2xskWL5', 'lifecycleState' => 'PUBLISHED', 'specificContent' => array('com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent' => array('shareCommentary' => array('text' => 'L\'assistant marketing supervise la gestion des plannings et de l\'agenda de ses supérieurs, de l\'organisation de rencontres ou des déplacements. • Occasionnellement, il peut être amené à faire de la prospective par téléphone (phoning) ou par email (mailing). • Avec le chargé d\'études, il peut mener des analyses statistiques et assurer une veille des activités de la concurrence et en matière règlementaire.'), 'shareMediaCategory' => 'NONE')), 'visibility' => array('com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility' => 'PUBLIC')), 'on_progress' => object(Closure))
```

But when I want to share a post it throws the following error :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden returned for "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts".
```

The user in linkedin has admin right on the company page and the app has the following right : r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social

My guess is that OAuth 2.0 scopes needs to be changed but I cannot find out where to allow access to the functionality.

Comment: Can you share the network request and response (in full)?

Comment: Thanks for your question : just added the request in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the problem.

While requesting the token, I did not grant « share » right to it.

Every thing works fine.